# What is the meaning of -(sp) in unix v6 Assembly?

Tags: unix, assembly, pdp-11

What's the meaning of `-(sp)`?

I am reading code of Unix V6, on PDP-11 the old OS.

I already know the meaning of `sp`, this is stack pointer.
Is this same as `-1(sp)`?

Comment: You need to provide more context. Also, please indicate what architecture you're asking about.

Comment: I pulled out my old PDP-11 assembly language book (by Thomas Frank). It has been a while, but I can confirm that SP (aka R3) supports pre-decrement and post-decrement. (as well as increment variants). It supports 1 and 2 byte increment/decrement. -(sp) would pre-decrement in a similar fashion as peter described for the m68k.

Comment: for example, There is `-(sp)` in m40.s where definition of _idle.

Comment: Was it something like `_idle:
 mov PS,-(sp)` ?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes.
why move PS to minus stackpointer? what is -(sp)?

Comment: It works like `push` in other architectures . you decrement _sp_ first and then move data to that location.  `mov PS,-(sp)` moves the WORD value from memory location pointed to by `PS` to the memory location *sp*-2 . My recollection on most PDP-11 assemblers is that _MOV_ assumes WORD (2 byte values), _MOVB_ is byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer was written before the question was clarified to PDP-11.  I guessed that it looked like an m68k pre-decrement addressing mode.

Michael Petch confirms that PDP-11's `-(SP)` syntax decrements by 1 or 2 bytes depending on operand size, so it was almost certainly the inspiration for Motorola's syntax.

---

[This page](http://alanclements.org/68kaddressingmodes3.html) explains that `-(A0)` syntax means to pre-decrement the pointer by the width of the operand.

- In a `MOVE.L`, it decrements by 4.  (like C `*(sp-=4)`)
- In a `MOVE.W`, it decrements by 2.
- In a `MOVE.B`, it decrements by 1.  (Unless the address register is A7, aka SP, in which case it still decrements by 2 so it stays aligned!)

Similarly, `+(A0)` works the same way as a post-increment operator.

**They work like x86's PUSH (pre-decrement the stack pointer) and POP (post-increment the stack pointer)**.

Answer (score 0):

`-(sp)` means decrement the register `sp` before its used.

Because `sp` is the stack pointer this is the usual way to write to the stack

```
mov r0,-(sp)
```

will for example save (or push) the register r0 on the stack, and

```
mov (sp)+,r0
```

will pop the value and restore the register again.